# Insert a header in a LibreOffice Writer document

Tags: libreoffice-writer, headers, page-numbers

I am editing a book in LibreOffice Writer.

The first page is the title page; the second page is the table of contents; the third page is Page 1, and on this page I wish to create a right-justified header to read:

> Author's Name / BOOK TITLE / 1.

Each subsequent page will have the same header text, but with pages numbering consecutively, 2 through the end of the book.

How is all of this done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new page style for the content:

   - <kbd>F11</kbd> or Menu `Format` -> `Styles and Formatting`;
   - Select Page styles (fourth button from left):

     [image]
   - right-click inside the styles list, select `New...`;
   - edit the new page style's properties:

     - on the `Organizer` tab, enter a name describing the style (e.g. "Content");
     - on the `Header` tab, enable the header.
2. Insert a page break, changing the page style after the TOC:

   - put the cursor at the end of the TOC;
   - Menu `Insert` -> `Manual Break...`;
   - Type: `Page Break`, Style: `Content` (the name you've assigned to the new page style in step 1), enable `Change page number`, set value to `1`:

     [image]
3. On the first page of the content:

   - click into the header
   - insert the static text `Author's Name / BOOK TITLE /` as usual;
   - insert the page number using menu `Insert` -> `Field` ->  `Page Number`
   - apply right alignment to the header.