# How to set different page numbers in footers per page?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, page-numbers

I have uploaded a simple ODT file: https://ufile.io/26f07

We are trying to achieve this in LibreOffice Writer:

- First page: **No** page number should be visible in the footer
- Second page: A page number needed as footer, so "**1**"
- Third page: **No** page number should be visible in the footer
- Fourth page: A page number needed as footer, so "**3**"
- Fifth page: ... A page number needed as footer, so "**4**" ...

We just don't know how to do this... Already tried on another forum, no luck: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/89058/how-exactly-can-i-set-different-footers-in-libreoffice-4282/

Can someone describe how to do this? Or is it impossible, cannot be done?

Comment: LibreOffice Help has already explained here: [Defining Different Headers and Footers](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Different_Headers_and_Footers). That can be done by "Styles and Formatting" in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: use page styles to define different headers/footers for even and odd pages in a document

Comment: Its not about "even and odd pages"

Comment: Earlier comments have hinted that it is possible. But answers related to "Styles and Formatting" can be lengthy and tedious to write. More hints: [This older answer](http://superuser.com/a/921107/109256) has similar steps, which is sadly underappreciated.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I have different text in the footer on every page of a Word document?](//superuser.com/q/47345/354511)

Comment: There are two answers posted below at this time. Else, best answer is more practice (trials and errors) and [self-answer](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer), which is how I have figured out this six years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Styles and Formatting" in LibreOffice Writer.

That allows users to customize different things per page. This includes how to set different page numbers in footers per page. Users are required to be familiar with two important features in LibreOffice Writer: **Page Styles** and **Page break** (or **Manual break** for more control).

The following screenshot shows that it is possible to set different page numbers in footers per page.

[image: LibreOffice Writer result overview]

Note that above screenshot has increased font size, reduced page size and reduced zoom scale to show the result, which is otherwise too small for overview.

### Follow five steps

Open LibreOffice with a new text document (or run LibreOffice Writer). In the menubar, select **View** and followed by **Styles and Formatting** (or press <kbd>F11</kbd>). There are five steps to follow:

1. Select **Page Styles** and create a new style with new name i.e. "Added Footer"
2. Modify the new style and enable **Footer**.
3. Insert **Manual Break**, select a style i.e. "Added Footer" and change page number (if enabled, default is `1` to restart page number).
4. Show **Footer** (click on footer area).
5. Insert **Field**, select **Page Number** (result is `1` according to step 3).

At this point, you will have two pages of blank document: The first page has no footer; The second page has footer with page number.

To proceed, follow step 3 *but* this time select `Default Style` from the dropdown list. This will create third page without the footer/page number. Then repeat step 3 *exactly as first time* i.e. the new style to create fourth page with the footer/page number and so forth.

### Additional notes

If you didn't get similar result, then you might have done something different:

- Using **Page Break** (wrong) instead of **Manual Break** (correct). Doing the wrong will not show the dialog to change the style.
- Placing the cursor inside the footer (wrong) instead of cursor within page content area (correct) to insert **Manual Break**. Doing the wrong will disable the last option "Page Break" in the dialog.

For more sophisticated formatting, repeat step 1 until step 3 to create additional page style. In step 2, users could define the page style more than what have been explained above.

For automated style selection, repeat step 2 to modify the page style. Then select **Organizer** tab and change "Next Style" to something else as desired. If this is done properly, then only use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a **Page Break** (correct) instead of **Manual Break** (optional).

**Disclaimer**: This answer is intended to be a generic guide for using "Styles and Formatting" in LibreOffice Writer, which means details have been omitted on purpose. That being said, this answer should suffice to understand the basic idea before proceeding to further customize the end result of text document.

### References

- [Creating a Page Style Based on the Current Page - LibreOffice Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Creating_a_Page_Style_Based_on_the_Current_Page)
- [Page Numbers - LibreOffice Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers)
- [Page numbering - Apache OpenOffice Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Page_numbering)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by using different page styles. The only problem is that you'll have to insert a manual page break after the first page. So, you can't let the content flow between the first and second (physical) page.

If adding a manual break after the first page is ok, just do the following:

1. Define four page styles (`my1stpagestyle` to `my4rthpagestyle`);
2. Modify `my2ndpagestyle` and `my4rthpagestyle` to have a footer;
3. Modify `my2ndpagestyle` to have `my3rdpagestyle` as as `Next Style` (on the `organizer` tab); modify `my3rdpagestyle` to have `my4rthpagestyle` as as `Next Style` in the same way;
4. Assign `my1stpagestyle` to the first page;
5. At the end of the first page, enter a manual page break (Menu Insert -> Manual Break); from the Style combobox, select `my2ndpagestyle`, enable "change page number" to start from 1.

Interim result:

- first page has no footer;
- second and fourth (and all fourth + n pages) will have a footer;
- third page will have no footer.

Now, for the final touch: In the footer of the second and of the fourth page, enter a page number field. That's all.

This will have the following effect:

- first page has its own page style with no page number;
- pagination will start from the second page, with no page number on the third page;
- text body content can flow starting from the second page, because the solution doesn't require manual breaks from the second page onwards.